# Assign textfield to each checked option in a checkboxes field

Tags: 7, entities

Lets say I have a checkboxes field and when I check one of the options, I would like a textfield to appear so I can assign a number (quantity) to it. Every option I check would have its own textfield.

For example, I have a "Fruits" field and I want to be able to say how many of each fruit I have. So it would be something like that:

```
[x] Apple (3)
[] Grape
[x] Orange (2)
```

Is there any module that does something similar to that?

Edit:

Another thing that would do the work for me would be a select list of numbers for each option. So by default the options are like that:

```
[0] Apple
[0] Grape
[0] Orange
```

So I can simply change the number of fruits in each option by selecting in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module should be suitable for this

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition.

Comment: Well, I don't think it will work if I have a variable number of options and I want to have a field assigned to each one of the checked options. That would work if I wanted a single textfield (or a defined number of fields) to appear when I check any option. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You said about variable number of options but each of these options have a name (Apple, Grape, Orange and so on). By which way you want to assign this names?

Comment: These options are actually nodes and I use a view for filtering them. So any time I add/delete a node, the number of options will change. That's why I can't create a defined number of fields and trigger each one of them when a option is checked.

Comment: How do you implement connection between nodes and Fruit field(s)?

Comment: This is just an example, but each fruit in this case is a node... and the title is the fruit name